# How switch between two contentpresenter binded to two separate contenttemplate and content?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to have two contentpresenter with two contenttemplate and content binded. wants to show only the contentpresenter in which the binding is not null

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddressModelTemplate">
        <Grid Background="White">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.LabelText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Adres" Margin="7"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Address, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="7"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Phone" Margin="7"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding PhoneNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="7"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="7" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Content="Zapisz" Margin="7" Width="80" Command="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.SaveCommand}"/>
                <Button Content="Anuluj" Margin="7" Width="80" Command="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.CancelCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ModelTemplate">
        <Grid >
            <Label Content="Only for show test"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding AddressModel}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AddressModelTemplate}"/>
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Model}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ModelTemplate}"/>
```

I try two contentpresenter like this but don't work.

`AddressModel` and `Model` are only model for binding so i dont show it

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by a single ContentPresenter where you do not explicitly set the ContentTemplate. Bind its `Content` property to a view model property that contains either a Model or an AddressModel.

The appropriate DataTemplate is automatically be chosen when you set its `DataType` property instead of assigning a `x:Key`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AddressModel}">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Model}">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ModelOrAddressModel}"/>
```

Comment: I dont understand this 'DataType="{x:Type local:AddressModel}"' . How you bind to a property? I cant do this with 'x:Type

Comment: The AddressModel and Model classes are in some namespace, for example the one referenced by `xmlns:local` in your XAML. It could of course be any other namespace, but you did not tell anything about these types. Then you would have a view model property of type `object` or of some other common base class of Model and AddressModel. When the property contains an AddressModel, the first DataTemplate would automatically be selected, if oi contains a Model, the second DataTemplate would be used.